# Algorithm LinkedList Problems How to Reduce the Common Intermediate Complex

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int testcase = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
            String input = br.readLine();
            LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
            int idx = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
                if(input.charAt(j) != '<' && input.charAt(j) != '>' && input.charAt(j) != '-') {
                    list.add(idx, input.charAt(j));
                    idx++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(input.charAt(j) == '<' && idx != 0) {
                    idx--;
                    continue;
                }
                if(input.charAt(j) == '>' && idx <= list.size() - 1) {
                    idx++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(input.charAt(j) == '-' && idx != 0) {
                    list.remove(idx - 1);
                    idx--;
                }
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
                bw.write(list.get(k));
            }
            bw.write('\n');
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

- input example

  ```
  2
  <<BP<A>>Cd-
  ThIsIsS3Cr3t
  ```
- output example

  ```
  BAPC
  ThIsIsS3Cr3t
  ```

The time limit is 2 seconds.

I used the BufferedReader instead of Scanner to speed up the performance and used BufferedWriter instead of System.out.println ().
However, the correct answer was a timeout problem.
Is there a way to reduce time complexity while using a linkedlist?

Comment: Do you have to use a LinkedList? I don't see what you're gaining by using that over an ArrayList.

Comment: @Ryan Probably a requirement of the problem. Also does a lot of inserting and deleting from the middle of the list, which is something linked lists are better at than arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` on a `LinkedList` is an O(N) operation, so if you're looking for speed, it should be avoided. You can instead use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) to get a cursor into the list that can be moved around much more efficiently compared to using an index, and used to insert or remove elements too.

You can also just use `input.charAt()` once and save the result in a `char` variable instead of calling it many times in a loop on the same index. It's a fast function call, but why call it more than you really need to, especially if working under a clock?

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))) {
            int testcase = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
                String input = br.readLine();
                LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
                ListIterator<Character> cursor = list.listIterator();

                for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
                    // I wish Strings were Iterable
                    char c = input.charAt(j);
                    if (c != '<' && c != '>' && c != '-') {
                        cursor.add(c);
                    } else if (c == '<' && cursor.hasPrevious()) {
                        cursor.previous();
                    } else if (c == '>' && cursor.hasNext()) {
                        cursor.next();
                    } else if (c == '-' && cursor.hasPrevious()) {
                        cursor.previous();
                        cursor.remove();
                    }
                }

                for (char c : list) {
                    bw.write(c);
                }
                bw.write('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note the *try-with-resources* for the reader and writer to automatically close them when done, a for-each loop to more efficiently iterate over the entire list when printing, and using if/else if in the logic of what to do with each character you read.

Comment: The string can be iterable....kinda:  for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {